# Will EventKit automatically sync with Google Calendar or Outlook ion iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-calendar-api, eventkit

I am trying to build a calendar app and I want the events and reminders could be synced to Google Calendar and Outlook. If I added events only using EventKit SDK, and the Google Calendar account was added. Will the events automatically synced to Google Calendar? Or do I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Events which are added to an EventKit calendar living on a Google, Exchange or iCloud account, will automagically sync. No extra work necessary.

Comment: Another question. If I want to syn with google in my app, after I have done authentication with google calendar api services, what else i need to do in order to make EventKit auto sync with google? What's the difference that between add google account in settings-calendar-accounts or in my app?

Comment: Comments are not for questions, questions are ;-) Also remember to read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask